# How to use JLabel as a String

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This is my `JLabel`. It gets a value from another function and I am able to display the value of `status` in the `JFrame`. But I am not able to print it in console.

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Demo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(300,150);
status = new JLabel("Status");
frame.add(status,BorderLayout.CENTER);
System.out.println(status);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Hello thank you for reply. i want to display an image which is having same name as values in status Jlabel. For example if status has a value "America" i want to display an image E:/America.png. But If i use status.getText() it returning name of status Jlabel not the value in status JLabel.

Answer (score 3):

## Adding an image to a JLabel

Having seen your further comment, I think I understand your confusion. You have a slight misconception about how images and JLabels work with each other.

You have been trying to pass an image path to your JLabel as a String parameter. However, the JVM will take this literally and will actually just display the image path, in text form, in your resulting JLabel.

What you need to do is pass an ImageIcon to your JLabel as a parameter and to this ImageIcon, you pass the file path.

For example:

```
ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("C:\\Folder\\File.png");    // Your image
JLabel imageJLabel = new JLabel(myImage);    // Your JLabel containing said image
```

Don't forget to import the ImageIcon library for this to work properly also with the import statement:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
```

### The Path String

I do want to make sure that you understand about these path String however. Of course, you can store the String in a variable and then pass this variable to the ImageIcon if you so wish.

For example:

```
String pathString = "C:\\Folder\\File.png";
ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(pathString);
```

But note that the path Strings will look a little different to what you are used to seeing when you usually deal with them in your operating system. For every backslash (\) which indicates you are moving through a directory, you will instead need to substitute in a double backslash (\\). This is because, in Java, the backslash is known as the escape character and indicates that the character following it is literal (i.e. it does not have any special function). Therefore, you need a backslash to tell the compiler that the backslash after it is literal and not being used as an escape character.

The path String can be manipulated as any other String can which makes it very convenient for adding or removing the file extension (e.g. .png) if you require this.

## Printing a JLabel to Console

You mention how you attempted to print the JLabel to console using

```
status = new JLabel("Status");
System.out.println(status);
```

What you do not understand is that a JLabel is a strictly graphical object and is meaningless in a console environment which deals solely with text. It therefore makes no sense to try to print an actual JLabel to the console.

I suspect what you are trying to do is print the contents of your JLabel to console. To do this, you need to ensure that what you are passing to

```
System.out.println();
```

is a String as this is all they understand [Simplified]. If the contents of your JLabel is text-based as your example is, then JLabel has a built in method for returning a String value for these contents.

```
status = new JLabel("Status");
String textFromJLabel = status.getText();    // Get the text from the JLabel
System.out.println(textFromJLabel);          // Print it to console
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable for for the status. Don't use a JLabel text. Also make sure the directory of your Status.png is correct. Try

```
 ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("E:\\Status.png");
```

Comment: Hello thank you for reply. i want to display an image which is having same name as values in status Jlabel. For example if status has a value "America" i want to display an image E:/America.png

Comment: It's better coding practice to declare that string in a separate value. i.e. 'String america = "Amerrica"' JLabel label = new JLabel(america); and ImageIcon imaage = new ImageIcon("E:\\" + america);'

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("E:\\"+status.getText()+".png");
```

normally file url looks like
C:\Users\Madhawa.se\Desktop\bac\gui\transparentglass.jpg

so it should be E:\America.png instead E:/America.png .isn't it

Comment: nice catch for those dashes

Answer (score 1):

You can only print Strings, and you're trying to print a JLabel. status is a JLabel Object (Type JLabel). You need a string to print. The text in a JLabel is separate from the JLabel, just like a car is separate from its license plate number.

```
status = new JLabel("Status");
String jlabelText = status.getText();  // Returns a String object
System.Out.println(jlabelText); // prints out the string variable

System.Out.println(status.getText()); // Or do it in one line
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` has **multiple overloads**.
When you pass an argument of type `JLabel`, you call `System.out.println(Object)`.

You can use `JLabel.getText()` to re-get its text.
Then, you can call `System.out.println(String)`.